# Creating a student from applicant model

Tags: python, html, django

How to create a student from my applicants models? and also giving the students a custom registration number that will be incrementing as new students register.

This my Applicant model

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ....
    registration_number = models.IntegerField()

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        if self.registration_number is None:
            last_student = Student.objects.order_by("-registration_number").first()
            if last_student is None:
                self.registration_number = 0
            else:
                self.registration_number = last_student.registration_number + 1

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Something like the following should handle the a prefix

```
prefix = "something"
qs = Student.objects.annotate(increment=Cast(SubStr("registration_number", len(prefix) + 1), output_field=models.IntegerField()))
last_student = Student.objects.order_by("-increment").first()
if last_student is None:
    self.registration_number = f"{prefix}0"
else:
    self.registration_number = f"{prefix}{last_student.increment + 1}
```

Comment: Thank You very much i really appreciate your solution and it works. What i can't figure out right now is how to assign some prefixes, student's department and year of entry before the registration number. Something like this: ('PES/23/0001').

Comment: Alright, really appreciate your effort, but its giving me this error (Cast.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_field'). I tried to find its solution but i couldn't.

Comment: Some parens weren't in the right place, I've fixed it